# .NET app terminates without getting into AppDomain.UnhandledException

Tags: .net, exception

I have an app which terminates unexpectedly sometimes in spite of existence of handlers for
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException, TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException events.

This is a WPF app with many P/Invoke interop code.
I've created "safety-net" with handlers for all "last resort" events (see above). But the app still fails with standard Windows error dialog missing all my handler.

What can be a cause for .net app termination and avoiding AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException ?

Can an exception in unmanaged thread be such a cause? If so what can I do with it?

Comment: Just an FYI, if an exception occurs in a child thread, it will not bubble up and you'll have to handle it in that thread.

Comment: @Sergey: but UnhandledException should fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLR cannot magically inject unhandled exception handling into native pinvoked code when that code itself doesn't take care of it.  Particularly any kind of hardware exception like AccessViolation in a thread that the CLR doesn't know about will terminate the app without a diagnostic.  You'll need to work with the owner or author of that code to improve the reliability and maintainability of that code.

Comment: but first I need to detect where the app terminates, which lib/component causes it to terminate. But whith default Windows error dialog it's impossible :(

Comment: CLR can't magically inject its logic into native code, but if that code causes main AppDomain to unload why CLR can't fire UnhandledException event _always_ ?

Comment: yeah, but this' happening on our customer side far far away from me

Comment: It isn't the CLR that terminates the app, it is the OS.  No AppDomain unloading takes place, it is shot in the head.  Obviously I cannot help you buy a plane ticket.  You really do need help from the people that wrote the buggy code.